# regular expression for validating format of maximum 5 digits in integer part & with maximum 2 decimal digits

Tags: java, regex

I would like to validate a string format that should only contain only numbers with also following conditions **both** satisfied:

1. If it is a integer number, the maximum number of digits is 5. For example, 12345 is fine, but 123456 is not fine.
2. If it is a number with decimal (or decimal fraction), the maximum digits after decimal mark is two. For example, 10,23 is fine, but 10,234 is not fine.

(NOTE: value use **comma or dot** as decimal point. **Please bear in mind that both of the two conditions have to be satisfied**. e.g. 123456,12 is not fine because the integer part is more than five digits)

I tried:

```
// This is the value to be validated
String value = fetchValue();
// my regular expression
String format = "^\\d{0,5}(?:[\\.\\,]\\d{0,2})?$";

boolean isValid = value.matches(format);
```

The code successfully validated the condition 1, but failed at condition 2, for example value 3,345 passed validation which is not expected.

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: If 12345 is fine, you should use `{0,5}`, not `{0,4}`, see [`^\d{0,5}(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/TGZSsn/1). Or do you mean the `1.1` is also invalid? Then use [`^\d{0,5}(?:[.,]\d{2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/TGZSsn/2).

Comment: As far as I know, in a character class (`[...]`) the backslashes are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code for it.

Comment: I can't reproduce https://regex101.com/r/6YHAFy/1

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. If I test with `String value = "3,345"`, the value of `isValid` is `false`. Are you sure `fetchValue()` returns the correct result (e.g. doesn't contain leading or trailing spaces)?

Comment: Main problem I see with this regex is that it accept `.` as valid number (since both integer and floating part can have length 0). Can you post examples of valid and invalid strings (include the less obvious ones)?

Comment: @Leem Checkout my answer below. Not sure if any other exp can be much simpler or more readable :D

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're trying for

`"^(?:\\d{1,5}(?:[.,]\\d{0,2})?|[.,]\\d{1,2})$"`

Readable version

```
 ^   
 (?:
      \d{1,5} 
      (?: [.,] \d{0,2} )?
   |  [.,] \d{1,2} 
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew if you want just one reqex;

You can always split it into two based on your conditions.

```
^\d{5}$

^\d{5}\.\d{2}$
```

**For JAVA**:

```
    matches can be used for matching the complete string and the following if should suffice

    if(num.matches("\\d{5}") ||num.matches("\\d{5}\\.\\d{2}") ) {

    }
```

Comment: @Pshemo My bad...! Edited the same. silly   '}' :P  Yeah because in java you got to escape '\' as well.